# ClientAliveInterval is not closing the idle ssh connection

Tags: linux, ssh, sysadmin

I have the task to close the idle ssh connection if they are idle for more than 5 minutes. I have tried setting these value on `sshd_config`

```
TCPKeepAlive no
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

But nothing seems to work the idle remains active and does not get lost even after 5 minutes of idle time.

Then I came across this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=254707 they guys says

> These are not for user-idle circumstances, they are - as that man page
> excerpt notes - for unresponsive SSH clients.  The client will be
> unresponsive if the client program has frozen or the connection has
> been broken.  The client should not be unresponsive simply because the
> human user has stepped away from the keyboard: the ssh client will
> still receive packets sent from the server.

I can't even use `TMOUT` because there are ssh client scripts that do not run bash program.

How to achieve this

Openssh version
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: Did you restart or reload the SSHD service after changing the files? Just checking in case not!

Comment: @shearn89 Yes ..

Comment: Sorry, are you OP? How come different account?